# Firebase Cloud Functions with Firebase Hosting : firebase.json "rewrites"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

Iam trying to create a Dynamic page using cloud functions, but when i serve using cli in local, Iam getting the index.html page from public folder.

I tried deploying the functions,hosting in firebase but the problem stands still, were iam getting the index.html page from public folder

So for iam trying the following codes - I think i must be wrong with "rewrites" part.

**/functions/index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.bigben = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const hours = (new Date().getHours() % 12) + 1 // london is UTC + 1hr;
  res.status(200).send(`<!doctype html>
    <head>
      <title>Time</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      ${'BONG '.repeat(hours)}
    </body>
  </html>`);
});
```

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",

    // Add the following rewrites section *within* "hosting"
   "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "/", "function": "bigben"
    } ]

  }
}
```

What iam trying to do is when we hit https://example.firebaseapp.com/ , we have to get bigben functions response data.

Please some one give your hands!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase Hosting will always prefer exact matches for static content over rewrites for performance reasons. Delete `index.html` from the public directory and your rewrite should begin working.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Bleigh, After removing index.html from the public directory i get the res from my function.

Comment: I know this is old but I just want to note the fact that this does not work for single page apps. The workaround is quite easy though ... insert the function rewrote before the global rewrite :)